# Haggis - taste difference between traditional and artificial casing

Tags: offal, traditional

Haggis, though considered purely Scottish could possibly have originated in the North of England.  It appears that the earliest known recipe/method is from the 15th century.  Just after a hunt, the offal was mixed with herbs, placed in the stomach lining of the (now dis-embowled) animal and cooked (a way of using parts of the animal that would otherwise have gone bad before being transported back to the manor house).

However it is now prepared all over the world and consumed on all days of the year, not just [Burns Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burns_supper).  Does using an [artificial casing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casing_(sausage)) instead of an animals stomach change the flavor in any way?  Is it necessary to obtain the stomach lining to match the taste of a traditional/authentic haggis?

Comment: So, this is a great question, but I'm not sure if "traditional/authentic" is what you really mean to ask about? Obviously it's not traditional if it's an artificial casing, but that doesn't mean there's a difference in flavor or anything else besides authenticity.

Comment: This question was edited by @Jefromi, however I disagree with the edit.  What was wrong with my original question?  Or am I missing the point here - should I take this to meta?

Comment: My first comment explains the issue I was trying to address. And like I said, the question is good, just that one bit was iffy, inviting opinions about what is and isn't authentic rather than the actual question of the effect of the casing. Feel free to ask on meta (or in [chat] since it's pretty simple) if you still don't agree.

Comment: I should add that I'm also happy for you to address that same issue in a different way! I'm not trying to dictate exact wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm positive the artificial casing changes the flavor because it tastes differently from natural casing. Besides, the stomach is bigger than most artificial casings.

So, it affects the flavor (not something I would worry about too much) and the size and therefore the cooking time.

Comment: Ah, hadn't thought about the cooking time - thank you for that piece of insight.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 I'm not sure if overcooking it would be a problem.